# How to convert 1.33 hours to 1:20 (hours:minutes)?

Tags: google-sheets

How to add minutes in Google Spreadsheet?

I've got a Google Spreadsheet that looks roughly like this:

```
min | min | min | min | min | total min | total time      
 20 |  20 |  20 |  20 |  20 |    80     |    1.33
```

But I want *Total Time* to show `01:20` or `01h20min` or something like that.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add minutes and seconds only, in a Google Spreadsheet?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/45860/how-to-add-minutes-and-seconds-only-in-a-google-spreadsheet)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just found this answer for Excel over at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/75618 and it worked for me in Google sheets as well.  Returns a serial number that displays correctly as HH:MM when your target cell is formatted as Hours.

```
="Minutes"/1440
```

(There are 1440 minutes in 24 hrs)

example:

```
=SUM(A1:A5)/1440
```

results in

```
0.055555555555556
```

and in turn converts to

```
01:20:00
```

(when cell formatted as "Hours")

Answer (score 4):

I had problems with with your answers, my fault for sure, or I have problems with the cell formats, that I misunderstood.

**BUT**, I wrote this one-shot formula that converts a cell with number to a text area with the desired `hh:mm` format.

You can change it adding other strings to the concatenate.

```
=concatenate(TEXT(Floor(H2),"00"),":",TEXT(round((H2-Floor(H2))*60),"00"))
```

`H2` is the cell containing the decimal number representing the hour of the day.

`4.81` will be translated into `04:49`

Comment: This was spot on - handles values higher than 24 hours as well. I adjusted it to this `=concatenate(TEXT(Floor(H4),"0"),"h ",TEXT(round((H4-Floor(H4))*60),"0"), "m")` to get `1h 9m` or `351h 23m` as an example.

Answer (score 3):

I've checked and fixed @RobGazy answer numbers (your number was valid for 4 rows i.e. SUM(A1:A4) but in question were 5 columns so must be SUM(A1:E1)).

Also could't find default "HOUR" *format* (in the menu) - this is *function* from the [DATE group for Google Spreadsheet](https://support.google.com/docs/topic/3105385?hl=en&ref_topic=3046366). If You apply `HOUR` format from `menu of advanced formats` You will get `01`, not `01:40` So... answer for Your example should be:

```
=SUM(A2:E2)/1440
```

gives results in F2

```
0,06944444444
```

and in turn converts to

```
01:40:00
```

(NOTE:
When cell formatted as "Hours" - so You have to choose to apply from quick menu [3 format - number](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470):

- -DATE- wrong
- TIME gives `01:40:00`
- DURATION gives `1:40:00`

and if You want `01:40` - choose from custom: `HOUR:MINUTE`
)